# How to escape the REPLACEMENT in a perl substitution?

Tags: regex, perl, bash, replace, escaping

**How do you completely escape the REPLACEMENT part of a perl subsitution with the `s//` operator?** `\Q` and `\E` do *not* work as, shown below:

For context, this comes up when using perl to do big recursive search and replace operations driven from a bash script. This is not an easily avoidable situation.

Take this script for example:

```
$ cat example.sh
#!/bin/bash
set -v -x
EMAIL=user@example.org
echo "EMAIL = $EMAIL"
echo "Email address: here" | perl -p -e "s/here/$EMAIL/"
echo "Email address: here" | perl -p -e "s/here/\\Q$EMAIL\\E/"
echo "Email address: here" | perl -p -e "s/here/${EMAIL/@/\\@}/"
```

Let's run it:

```
$ ./example.sh
EMAIL=user@example.org
+ EMAIL=user@example.org
echo "EMAIL = $EMAIL"
+ echo 'EMAIL = user@example.org'
EMAIL = user@example.org
```

So far so good. The shell isn't mangling anything and we are echoing what we expect.

```
echo "Email address: here" | perl -p -e "s/here/$EMAIL/"
+ echo 'Email address: here'
+ perl -p -e s/here/user@example.org/
Email address: user.org
```

Okay, that time the replacement wasn't quoted, so the `@example` part of the string got expanded (to nothing) and effectively disappeared. Okay, fine, let's escape it with our good friends `\Q` and `\E`:

```
echo "Email address: here" | perl -p -e "s/here/\\Q$EMAIL\\E/"
+ echo 'Email address: here'
+ perl -p -e 's/here/\Quser@example.org\E/'
Email address: user\.org
```

Well, that was unexpected! `\Q` and `\E` quoted the `.`, but they left the `@example` part unescaped! What is going on here?

```
echo "Email address: here" | perl -p -e "s/here/${EMAIL/@/\\@}/"
+ echo 'Email address: here'
+ perl -p -e 's/here/user\@example.org/'
Email address: user@example.org
```

Okay, so this finally worked, but only because we used bash pattern expansion to do a search and replace. It worked in this particular case because this was an e-mail address. This would be incredibly tedious to do for all possible replacement metacharacters in a more general case.

So again, how do you escape the REPLACEMENT part of a perl subsitution completely when using the `s//` operator? Is it possible? There has to be a trick I'm missing. =)

**SOLVED**

ysth's answer suggested using `s'''`, which solves this simple example, but I couldn't use that in my real code, because I needed backreferences in my real use caes. However, ysth's answer and TLP's comment both proposed using `$ENV{...}`. As far as I can tell, this works perfectly so far in my real use cases, which must be able to use back-references.

Here is an updated version of the example shown above.

```
$ cat example-new.sh
#!/bin/bash
set -v -x
EMAIL=user@example.org
# Don't touch my delimiters!
echo "Email address goes >>>>>>here<<" | perl -p -e 's/(>+)here(<+)/$1$ENV{EMAIL}$2/'
```

It works as expected when running it:

```
$ ./example-new.sh
EMAIL=user@example.org
+ EMAIL=user@example.org
# Don't touch my delimiters!
echo "Email address goes >>>>>>here<<" | perl -p -e 's/(>+)here(<+)/$1$ENV{EMAIL}$2/'
+ echo 'Email address goes >>>>>>here<<'
+ perl -p -e 's/(>+)here(<+)/$1$ENV{EMAIL}$2/'
Email address goes >>>>>>user@example.org<<
```

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do here: `${EMAIL/@/\\@}`?

Comment: @TLP that is bash syntax for variable expansion with replacement.

Comment: Perhaps you should try replace `s/here/$EMAIL/` with `s/here/\$ENV{EMAIL}/`. Which is how you access environment variables in Perl. And/or also change `'` to `"` so you perhaps can remove the backslash.

Comment: @TLP your comment and ysth's answer both suggested `$ENV{...}` which was a great solution to this problem!

Comment: Indeed. You can use lookaround assertions in place of using string captures: `s/(?<=<)here(?=<)/$ENV{EMAIL}/` which saves the trouble of using `$1` etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

\Q\E are applied to the results of variable interpolation, so you can't keep @example from interpolating that way.

But you can use single quotes:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -v -x
EMAIL=user@example.org
echo "Email address: here" | perl -p -e "s'here'$EMAIL'"
```

or, if the email address may contain `'` or `\\`, let perl get $EMAIL from the environment:

```
export EMAIL=user@example.org
echo "Email address: here" | perl -p -e 's/here/$ENV{EMAIL}/'
```

Comment: The single-quotes way doesn't work in some real cases because the replacement also uses `$1`, etc, but the `$ENV{...}` method looks like it would work perfectly.

Comment: that wouldn't work with `$1`; can you show an example of that usage with your expected output?

Comment: I updated my question with a SOLUTION section to show how your `$ENV{...}` suggestion works with my need for `$1`.

Comment: ah, I thought you meant $1 in $EMAIL